# MagicalRecord save new values of properties issues

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a Player property. I pass it to another controller. In this controller I modify properties of player. So when i go back to the previous controller. I can see all new values of each property of player. But when I reload app the controller shows me the first values of the player.

I create my player here:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    Player *player = [Player MR_createInContext:localContext];
    [player MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:responseData];


} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Then I fetch all players that are already created and try to modify some property via '='

```
player.name = @"Alex";
```

but it works only for the current "running" as I said when I reload app, the value of name is the same when it was created at first time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the property after you edit it. Do something like this.

```
Player *players = [Player MR_findAllInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
for (Player *player in players) {
    player.name = @"modified name";
}

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

You can also switch out `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]` with `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]` if you want to use a local version or `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]`. I did read somewhere not to use the `MR_contextForCurrentThread` in an old version of MagicalRecord but not sure if that still applies. I am using it without issues.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to use contextForCurrentThread any more because it is not 100% safe when using parallel GCD queues.

Comment: @Bot thank you. I am using magical records 2.0.8 and seems it has not got  saveToPersistentStoreAndWait method. I use this version because there are not issues with the import feature.